# Открытие текста в одинаковых классах

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатие на ссылку «Открыть спаны», открывались все спаны с классом «date». Демо http://jsfiddle.net/tBxQG/1/

```
<a href="#" onclick="open('date'); return false">Открыть спаны</a>

<span class="date" style="display:none">Утро</span><h4>Понедельник</h4>
<ol>
    <li>Training</li>
    <li>Training</li>
    <li>Training</li>
</ol>
<span class="date" style="display:none">День</span><h4>Вторник</h4>
<ol>
    <li>Training</li>
    <li>Training</li>
    <li>Training</li>
</ol>
...
<span class="date" style="display:none">Вечер</span><h4>Воскресенье</h4>
<ol>
    <li>Training</li>
    <li>Training</li>
    <li>Training</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tBxQG/2/

Answer (score 1):

вот решение без jQuery, и кажется, без html5:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var opens = document.getElementsByClassName('open_span');
    for (var i = 0; i < opens.length; i++) {
        opens[i].onclick = open_span;
    }

    function open_span(e) {
        var targetclass = this.attributes.getNamedItem('data-target').value;
        var targets = document.getElementsByClassName(targetclass);
        for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            if (hasClass.apply(targets[i], ["open"])) {
                removeClass.apply(targets[i], ["open"]);
            } else {
                addClass.apply(targets[i], ["open"]);
            }
            console.log(i,targets.length);            
        }
    }
};

function hasClass(cls) {
    return this.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(cls) {
    if (!hasClass.apply(this,[cls])) this.className += " " + cls;
}

function removeClass(cls) {
    if (hasClass.apply(this,[cls])) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
        this.className = this.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tBxQG/7/

а вот c jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open_span', function () {
    $('span.'+$(this).data('target')).toggleClass('open');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tBxQG/6/